# Is it possible for Magento 1.x payment plugin to allow the administrator to edit the app/code/../local/etc/config.xml file in the method's settings?

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods

So that the administrator of the Magento 1.x site can change the name of the payment method that comes up on the checkout page. Is it possible to offer such an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to edit config.xml, usually payment modules allows you to change the title/name at Magento Backend -> System -> Sales -> Payment Methods

If it's a custom module you can check: http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-create-magento-payment-module/

Regards,
Pablo